# How to setup Magento 2.x with Asynchronous Messaging using Docker

Tags: magento2.3, docker

We wanted to setup **Magento 2.x with Asynchronous Messaging using Docker**.
Previously we did the docker setup for Magento 2.x(Synchronous).

We have tried to search for a relative reference for Asynchronous Messaging setup on our Docker VM, but couldn't find anything.

Could you please share some reference which can help us with the setup.
Appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: We are looking for some reference on how to configure Asynchronous Messaging for operations performed in Magento tenant using APIs, could someone please help to share some pointers